# Apache to Nginx mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache-http-server, nginx, mod-rewrite

I converted some mod_rewrite rules for nginx and they were working fine when I tested it locally but for some reason they are not working on my website.

Can anyone help where I'm going wrong?

Apache rules:

```
<filesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js|php)$">

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

DefaultLanguage en-US

</filesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article.*$ / [R=301,L]



RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*\.* /loadpage.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*\.html /courses/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Nginx converted rules:

```
 charset utf-8;
        error_page 404 /404.php;
location /article {
         rewrite ^/article.*$ / redirect;
        }

        location / {
         if (!-e $request_filename){
          rewrite ^/.*\.* /loadpage.php break;
          }
         }

          if (!-e $request_filename){
           rewrite ^/.*\.html /courses/index.php break;
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem

Your last rewrite rule is outside of any `location` block. Admittedly, I am not sure how nginx handles cases where there's both a rewrite rule inside a matching location block and inside `server` (I would assume it will always use the one inside `server` as that is what is evaluated first). What I am sure about however is that this leads to **unexpected results**.

---

### The solution

First and foremost, [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). Do not use it unless there's absolutely no other way to achieve the same result (which really only happens in very obscure situations).

A better alternative to check the existence of a file is the [try_files](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive.

> **Checks the existence of files in the specified order and uses the first found file for request processing**; the processing is performed in the current context. The path to a file is constructed from the file parameter according to the root and alias directives. It is possible to check directory’s existence by specifying a slash at the end of a name, e.g. “$uri/”. **If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made.**

Your rewrite rules would then look like this:

```
charset utf-8;
error_page 404 /404.php;

location /article {
  rewrite ^/article.* / redirect;
}

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /loadpage.php?$args;
}
```

The last rewrite rule, which is likely to be the problematic one, would look something like this with `try_files` inside its own location block:

```
location ~ \.html$ {
  try_files $uri /courses/index.php?$args;
}
```

The `~` modifier tells nginx that this location uses a regular expression. It matches all URI's that end with `.html`. This location block gets preference over the other location blocks because it is *more specific* (regular expression location blocks are examined before "normal" ones). [More info on nginx location block selection](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms).

---

### Additional notes & resources

The `$` after `^/article.*` is redundant since you are matching *all* characters behind it anyway. Appending `?$args` to the URI of the `try_files` directive ensures that all `GET` parameters are passed along to it.

- [Nginx location modifiers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

Comment: Thanks for such a great piece of information. On applying your rules, my home page was being redirected to loadpage.php, so I added


location /.* {
         try_files $uri /loadpage.php?$args;
       }


My 1st rule and 3rd rule were working even before but it is the 2nd rule that is creating problems. What 2nd rule says is, everything after localhost/ that doesn't matches any file on the server should be redirected to loadpage.php

for eg.

localhost/dskjdnjsdn
localhost/sjhdksjhd.jpg
localhost/djkshdjksd.php
or any extension

Comment: I hope you can understand my previous comment, it's a little messed up. 2nd rule is still not working I don't know why.

Comment: Ah, I see. Assuming you have an index defined, you could then probably just do this: `location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /loadpage.php?$args;
}`. The second `$uri/` will match the index when there's nothing behind the / of the URI.

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas. It is working now, but localhost/anyname.php is still not working. It is being redirected to 404 instead of loadpage.php. All other extensions like localhost/anyname   localhost/anyname.jpg   localhost/anyname.phpp are being redirected successfully.

Comment: @Axel That is probably because you are catching `\.php$` somewhere to redirect all requests ending in `.php` to PHP. Remember the location block selection algorithm: regular expressions are evaluated first, so what happens is that it sees `localhost/anyname` **.php**, which matches the `\.php$` block, which in turns tries to pass this to the PHP parser without checking it first. A solution could be to add `try_files $uri /loadpage.php?$args;` to your `\.php$` location block.

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas. I didn't even think about the php requests being passed to PHP parser. Do you have any experience with migrating php website and a wordpress blog from Apache to Nginx? I'm working on this and I keep facing problems with the migration.

Comment: @Axel I don't have direct experience with that specifically, however I do have plenty of experience with web stacks in general (Nginx/Apache/PHP).

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough rep to chat. Anywhere we can talk more easily, I'm having a hard time setting up wordpress permalinks in nginx and also the redirects at localhost are being applied to localhost/blog as well where my wordpress is installed.

Comment: @Axel I believe I can open a chat room (never tried before), I have no idea though if you will be able to chat in it, we can try of course.

Comment: I guess not. One needs to be 15 rep at least to join a chat.

Comment: Any idea with this Thomas? https://superuser.com/questions/1429016/wordpress-permalinks-not-working-in-nginx

Comment: I've never used discord before, I've sent you a friend request. Did you receive it?

Comment: @Axel Yep, I should be in your list